# Propagate arguments to two commands combined with &&

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, command-line-interface

I have two commands in package.json combined with '&&':

```
  "scripts": {
    "someAction": "node dist/scripts/actionOne && node -r dist/scripts/actionTwo"
  },
```

Is it possible to call this script from cli, passing arguments to both 'actionOne' and 'actionTwo' ?

When calling
`npm run someAction -- firstArg, secondArg` args are passed only to 'actionOne' script.

*Number of args expected by actionOne and actionTwo are identical.

Comment: Consider utilizing a [shell function](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Functions) in your npm script, then reference the args in the function body using the `$@` [special parameter](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters): For example define your npm script as: `"someAction": "func() { node dist/scripts/actionOne \"$@\" && node -r dist/scripts/actionTwo \"$@\"; }; func"` - then run the following command`npm run someAction -- firstArg secondArg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the [docs](https://github.com/mysticatea/npm-run-all/blob/master/docs/npm-run-all.md), it looks like `npm-run-all` would work with **argument placeholders.**

We can use placeholders to give the arguments preceded by -- to scripts.

```
$ npm-run-all build "start-server -- --port {1}" -- 8080
```

This is useful to pass through arguments from npm run command.

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "start": "npm-run-all build \"start-server -- --port {1}\" --"
    }
}

$ npm run start 8080

> example@0.0.0 start /path/to/package.json
> npm-run-all build "start-server -- --port {1}" -- "8080"
```

So you could do something like this:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "start": "npm-run-all dist/scripts/actionOne -- --arg {1} && dist/scripts/actionTwo -- --arg2 {2}"
    }
}
```

Then:

```
npm run start arg1 arg2
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is a real answer, I wanna know.  But also, you can make a script like this

some-action.sh

```
set -e
dist/scripts/ActionOne $@
dist/scripts/ActionTwo $@
```

and then put this in your package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "someAction": "bash some-action.sh"
},
```